# SQL, Joining two or more table and return result

Tags: sql, join

```
CREATE TABLE Flight 
(
    FlightID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FlightDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    Origin VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Destination VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    MaxCapacity INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PricePerSeat DECIMAL NOT NULL

)
CREATE TABLE FlightBooking 
(
    BookingID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CustomerID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FlightID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    NumSeats INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Status CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    BookingTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    TotalCost DECIMAL

)
status = Reserve, Held Cancelled or Expired (only reserved and held are taken into account)
CREATE TABLE SeatBooking
(
    BookingID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PassengerID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SeatNumber CHAR(4) 

)
```

Is there anyway I can get the status of the seat if the flightid is given and and aggregate number of total available seats , total reserved seats and total held seats

Comment: Status is a char(1) but you list out some words.  How can we answer this is you don't tell us the magic code letters for status?

Comment: What SQL platform are you using -- SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, MySQL, SQLite, or other?

Comment: @user2266419 - If the answer was helpful please upvote and select the checkmark as the correct answer -- don't edit your answer with a thank you.  This means no one can see the question.

Comment: "Is there anyway I can get the status of the seat" - which seat?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway I can get the status of the seat if the flightid is
>   given and and aggregate number of total available seats , total
>   reserved seats and total held seats

Yes there is! I'm assuming use of Oracle, SQL Server or DB2 and use a CTE.  If you don't have one of those you have to make use of a sub-query or temp table.

Total reserved seats if 'R' is the code for status (you could limit this to a single flight if you wanted to in the where clause, but these queries give you values for all flight ids):

```
SELECT SUM(NumSeats), FlightID
FROM FlightBooking 
WHERE Status = 'R'
GROUP BY FlightID
```

Total held seats if 'H' is the code for status:

```
SELECT SUM(NumSeats), FlightID
FROM FlightBooking 
WHERE Status = 'H'
GROUP BY FlightID
```

Total available seats is then:

```
  WITH used AS
   (
      SELECT SUM(NumSeats) as used, FlightID
      FROM FlightBooking 
      WHERE Status in ('R','H')
      GROUP BY FlightID
   )
   SELECT F.MaxCapacity-U.Used, F.FlightID
   FROM used U
   JOIN Flight F ON U.FlightID = F.FlightID
```

Comment: but the problem is when I am running its not showing me the values when status is Expired or Cancelled , sorry for that I wasn't very clear my question maybe can you please tell me how can I return the table when the status are also E or C(when its E or C it doesnt have an impact on the Max Capacity ofcourse)

Comment: @user2266419 - Yes there is a problem -- you ignored my comments and did not read my answer.  It **is clear how to use other codes from my answer**.  Also, answer the two questions I put in the comments.

Comment: I am sorry I missed that part the status is 'R','E','H' or 'C' where R stands for reserved , expired , hold , and  cancelled

Answer (score 0):

Given the flight ID, you should be able to get the total available seats, total reserved seats and total held seats like so:

```
select MaxCapacity - Reserved - Held as Available, Reserved, Held
from
(select f.MaxCapacity,
        sum(case b.status when 'R' then b.NumSeats end) Reserved,
        sum(case b.status when 'H' then b.NumSeats end) Held
 from Flight f
 left join FlightBooking b on f.FlightID = b.FlightID
 where f.FlightID = ?) sq
```